# Trouble creating wiki page template for content types!

Tags: wiki, content-type

Just assumed it was as easy as creating a document [content type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472236.aspx) but when I tried it for the first time, to my surprise I could not do it. Where do I download a wiki page template? Why can’t I just open up a wiki library in windows explorer, similar to that in any document library? I [just tweeted](http://twitter.com/Proficients/status/21013233317) about this topic but no reply yet that answered my question.  Currently I'm reading some articles but still looking for an answer. Thanks!

After not getting an answer to this [same post on TheSUG](http://www.thesug.org/Discussions/_layouts/Community/Groups/DiscussionPost.aspx?PostID=1572) I thought I would try [SharePointOverflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/1271/proficients), and I will keep going until I get an answer :). This seems like a fairly simple straight forward question, so much so I’m almost embarrassed to ask it.   **How do you download a wiki page to your desktop, in order to use it for a wiki page template (Having trouble doing so)?** The template that SharePoint uses for their wiki page library does not suffice, the font is too small and we would like to add our own standard links.  As it stands now we have to copy and paste a “template” layout each time we create a new wiki page. Our goal is to create a standard SharePoint Wiki Page using contnet types, so every time a new page is created it uses OUR template, not SharePoint’s basic version.

Would someone please help us!  We know it is a simple question but having trouble finding the time to figure it out.  We have posted this same question on [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com/proficients), TheSUG and now SharePointOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Your tweet linked to a great resource from EndUserSharePoint.com.

Did you try the customization Mark linked to in the comments to that post, [Wiki - Customization](http://www.bitsofsharepoint.com/BlogPoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=39)? I haven't tried it, but the theory is sound. Modify the master page for the wiki site. Use a combination of CSS and Javascript to fix up what you can't or don't want to do from the mater page directly.